# How to add multiple rows in dataTable pdf header

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, pdfmake

I use pdfMake to export dataTable content to a pdf. I need to add a nice looking header at the top of the table and also a title.

I have this in my dataTable pdf export script.

```
doc['header']=(function() {
                        return {

                            columns: [
                                {
                                    alignment: 'left',
                                    image: logo,
                                    width: 70
                                }
                            ],
                            margin: 20
                        }
                    });
```

How do i make the logo to take full-width and also add another line of text below the logo in the center.

Answer (score 0):

To add another line below the logo, you can add additional line below

```
doc['header']=(function() {
                        return {

                            columns: [
                                {
                                    alignment: 'left',
                                    image: logo,
                                    width: 70
                                },
                                {
                                    alignment: 'center',
                                    text: '\ntext here',
                                    width: 70
                                    margin: [L,T,R,B]
                                }
                            ],
                            margin: 20
                        }
                    });
```